# Using django-dbbackup with parameters not working in view

Tags: python, django, database-backups

I am trying to make a view for my user to save and restore database using django-dbbackup. I need my user to be able to decide the name of file for saving and the file to be restored using FormView. But commands **dbbackup** and **dbrestore** are not accepting parameters when I call them with **call_command** in view.py, but doing `manage.py dbbackup -o mycopy` in terminal works. Still learning.

error in backup:

*raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'dbbackup -o mycopy'*

Is there another way to restore and backup without using terminal?